# Is there a sysprep similar stuff to neutralize the system before imaging?

Tags: debian

I need to clone a debian 11 bullseye system and deploy it on other systems if needed. I am trying to neutralize the system before i do the imaging. I used some commands but they resulted in affecting the image, like ssh connection not can't be done or the system (installed from the image) freezes randomly.

Here is what i did:

```
# Reset interfaces
    sudo rm /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
    sudo rm /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases
    sudo sed -i '/^allow-hotplug eth/d' /etc/network/interfaces
    sudo sed -i '/^iface eth/d' /etc/network/interfaces
    sudo sed -i '/^address/d' /etc/network/interfaces
    sudo sed -i '/^netmask/d' /etc/network/interfaces
    sudo sed -i '/^gateway/d' /etc/network/interfaces
    sudo sed -i '/^dns-nameservers/d' /etc/network/interfaces


# reset hostname
echo "debian" | sudo tee /etc/hostname
sudo sed -i '/127.0.1.1/d' /etc/hosts
echo "127.0.1.1    debian" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts

# remove ssh host keys
sudo rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*

# clean APT cache
sudo apt-get clean

reset random number generator pool:
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/lib/systemd/random-seed bs=512 count=1
sudo rm /var/lib/systemd/random-seed

# remove udev persistent rules
sudo rm /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
sudo rm /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-cd.rules

# clear swap and temporary files
sudo rm /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
sudo rm /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-cd.rules

# Remove SSH Keys and user credentials:
sudo rm -rf /root/.ssh
sudo rm -rf /home/*/.ssh
sudo passwd -l root # Lock root account to prevent login

# remove system logs
sudo find /var/log -type f -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;


# Clear bash histroy and logs
cat /dev/null > ~/.bash_history
history -c && history -w
sudo cat /dev/null > /root/.bash_history
sudo history -c && sudo history -w
sudo rm -rf /var/log/* /var/log.*/*


# shutdown system
sudo shutdown -h now
```

After runing those commands, i created the image and deployed that on a different system that is similar to the image-system (same hardwaresj and from same manufacture). I also changed the hostname by changing them in

> /etc/hosts & /etc/hostname

and then i ran

> sudo hostname -F /etc/hostname

But after i installed the image on the other system, it started to work cracz. like ssh connection not possible, even if i activate it in firewall and also the system started to freeze randomly.

Is there a automated way like sysprep in windows to do the neutralizing in debian ?

Comment: Do I understand this right: You cloned a system that had issues and are now surprised that the new system also has those issues?

Comment: How did you clone the image?
What I would have done is to shut it down cleanly, boot on a USB key and then do a `dd` of the disk(s).